# Ruby - Capybara - ArgumentError: invalid keys

Tags: ruby, rspec, capybara

I'm executing a code, where i verify if the input is disabled, but an error occurs.

### CODE

```
before(:each) do
    visit 'https://training-wheels-protocol.herokuapp.com/dynamic_controls'
end

it 'quando habilita o campo' do
    res = page.has_field? 'movie', disable: true
    puts res
end
```

### ERROR

```
 ArgumentError:
   invalid keys :disable, should be one of :count, :minimum, :maximum, :between, :text, :id, :class, :style, :visible, :exact, :exact_text, :normalize_ws, :match, :wait, :filter_set, :checked, :unchecked, :disabled, :multiple, :readonly, :with, :type, :name, :placeholder
 # ./spec/dynamic_control_spec.rb:8:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

---

**Can someone help me?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is telling you what options are valid to pass to `has_field?`. You should be passing `disabled: true` rather than :disable.